# Twig - Do Not Escape '&'

Tags: php, twig

I am escaping characters using the escape Twig filter `e` in my `<meta>` tag in-case they contain quotations which will break the tag. The issue is that it is escaping the and `&` character. I am wondering if there is a way to not escape the and sign?

`<meta property="description" content="{{ description | e }}" />`

Comment: Twig automatically converts special characters to their HTML equivalents... so... Why do you need to escape anything to begin with?

Comment: example: the string description should, with native twig functionality, be converting " to &#34; - there shouldn't be a reason to use escape..

Comment: @skrilled In English, I do not see my description string converted to HTML entities. It still remains as normal english characters. If there is a quotation in my description string, that would break my meta tag.

Comment: I don't see TWIG converting the quotations when I just do `<meta property="description" content="{{ description }}" />`

Comment: are you not using twig in combination with symfony? maybe that's where my assumption is wrong then. symfony default config will autoescape twig templates as I described, have to go out of your way to remove that :/

Comment: you could always just do description|e|replace({'\&':'&'}) ?

Comment: @skrilled Haha, I didn't think of using a `replace` filter. That worked beautifully! Can you post that response as a reply so I can select that as my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could always just use replace as a hack fix ;)

```
description|e|replace({'\&':'&'})
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this would work in your case, but generally speaking escaping of html attributes should be done by specifying that context explicitly: `...|e('html_attr')`, cf. [the escape filter docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html).

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `html_attr` escape mode because you are inserting the result into a `content` attribute.

```
<meta property="description"
      content="{{ description | e('html_attr') }}" />
```

BTW: if this is HTML not XML, your `meta` tag should have a `name` attribute, not a `property` attribute.

Comment: Old answer, but doing so makes all spaces become `&#x20;`

Comment: @ArendE true, because `html_attr` escape mode also needs to support unquoted attribute values, i.e. `<meta property=description content={{ description | e('html_attr') }}>`