# Twig escaping not working as expected

Tags: symfony, filter, escaping, twig

I'm using Symfony 2 and in a twig template I'm trying to write something as simple as that:

```
{% set temp = '<&>' %}
{{ temp|e }}
```

So I'm expecting to get the result: '& lt;& amp;& gt;' but still my result is: '<&>'. The other twig filters work properly. Am I doing something wrong? Isn't escape filter included by default in Symfony2?

Comment: What version of twig are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551286/twig-do-not-escape

Comment: @BRad not at all. The question you posted is about how to NOT escaping ambersand. My problem is that I cant get escaping to work. About my twig version is hard to tell. I use Symfony 2.5 so twig comes by default with Symfony.

Comment: If you want the unicode of `<&>` then why are you trying to escape it?  You shouldn't escape it if you are looking for the unicode.  Unless I am misunderstanding the issue. As a side note composer will hold all the versions for you.

Comment: 1. In my composer my twig extension is "~1.0" 2. My actual propblem is that I'm trying to do something like this example presented in Symfony cookbook :http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype. So according to the example: For this code in twig template: {{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e }}, on the rendered page, the result will look something like this: "&lt;div&gt;&lt;label class=&quot; required&quot;&gt; (...)". But I'm getting something like this: '<div id="form_images___name__"> (...)'.

Comment: Well it looks like your result is half way there.  The cookbook says your result should be... `<ul class="tags" data-prototype="&lt;div&gt;&lt;label class=&quot; required&quot;&gt;__name__&lt;/label&gt;&lt;div id=&quot;task_tags___name__&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;task_tags___name___name&quot; class=&quot; required&quot;&gt;Name&lt;/label&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;task_tags___name___name&quot; name=&quot;task[tags][__name__][name]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; maxlength=&quot;255&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;">`  Your id is close to theirs

Answer (score 0):

Twig determines the escaping strategy based on the file name extension in Symfony. You could try to rename the file to `*.html.twig`, set manually the strategy

```
{% set strategy = 'html' %}
```

or explicitly define the escaping strategy to use

```
{{ temp|e('html')
```